# Cannot POST error in react app while receiving POST submission from another page

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My application is connected to a payment gateway. I set a response page for it. Then after completed the payment process it will redirect to my page. They send it as a post submission. because of that, this error occurred. To check this I create 2 pages and pass some data to page 2 from page 1. At that time the same error occurred. Thank you.

- I am not using express
- I can't see webpack.config.js file in the project.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not `/receipt` instead of `/Receipt`?

Comment: Yes. I tried both ways by changing the route

Comment: can u add related code?